# Docker Compose " How to pass local KVM module to Container(Through YAML configuration)?" :: --device /dev/kvm

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I can able to pass the KVM module to container by "docker run" -- command

Example: docker run -d **--device /dev/kvm** --name android-container  someimage:tag.

How I can achieve same through docker-compose.yaml configuration?.

```
android-appium:
   image: budtmo/docker-android:emulator_13.0
   container_name: android-appium   
   restart: always 
   device: /dev/kvm
```

When I am trying the above I get syntax error saying

> unknown property device

Comment: Compose file version 3 supports [`devices:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#devices), plural, with a list value.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment from @David Maze

We can add device by

```
android-appium:
   image: budtmo/docker-android:emulator_13.0
   container_name: android-appium   
   restart: always 
   ports:
       - "5555:5555"
   devices: 
       - "/dev/kvm:/dev/kvm"
```

Thanks **David Maze**!